# dplyr'ish approach to simple subset/summarise function

Tags: r, function, dplyr, rlang

## Background

The provided function achieves the following:

- Subsets the provided data frame using user-provided expression
- Selects the desired column
- Applies custom summary function on resulting vector and returns scalar

### `base` approach

```
summarise_filtered <-
    function(df,
             subset_arg,
             summary_fun = c("min", "max", "median"),
             select_col) {
        summary_fun <- match.arg(summary_fun)

        sbst_vals <-
            subset.data.frame(
                df,
                subset = eval(parse(text = subset_arg)),
                drop = TRUE,
                select = eval(parse(text = select_col))
            )

        do.call(match.fun(summary_fun), list(sbst_vals))

    }
```

#### Results

```
summarise_filtered(mtcars, "am == 1", "min", "cyl")
# [1] 4
summarise_filtered(mtcars, "am == 1", "max", "cyl")
# [1] 8
```

## Challenge

I'm interested in re-writing the function above using `dplyr` pipe syntax. My initial attempt fulfils the basic requirements:

```
summarise_filtered_dplyrish <-
    function(df,
             subset_arg,
             summary_fun,
             select_col) {

        df %>%
            filter({{subset_arg}}) %>%
            summarise(across(.cols = {{select_col}}, .fns = summary_fun)) %>%
            pull({{select_col}})

    }
```

when called:

```
summarise_filtered_dplyrish(mtcars, am == 1, min, cyl)
# [1] 4
```

### Problem

I would like for the function to work using:

```
summarise_filtered_dplyrish(mtcars, "am == 1", "min", "cyl")
```

syntax, *in addition* to the the already working solution. How to do this? So far, the call above generates error:

#### Error

> Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`. x Input `..1` must be a
> logical vector, not a character. ℹ Input `..1` is `"am == 1"`. Run
> `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`min` and `cyl` can be easily handled by `ensym()`, which works with both strings and symbols. The expression `am == 1` requires a little bit more work. Let's define a helper function that parses an object only if it's a string:

```
str2expr <- function(.x) {if( is.character(.x) ) rlang::parse_expr(.x) else .x}
```

We can now capture the argument provided to `subset_arg` and parse it if it's a string:

```
summarise_filtered_dplyrish <-
    function(df,
             subset_arg,
             summary_fun,
             select_col) {

        subset_expr <- rlang::enexpr(subset_arg) %>% str2expr()

        df %>%
            filter( !!subset_expr ) %>%
            summarise(across(.cols = {{select_col}}, .fns = !!ensym(summary_fun))) %>%
            pull( !!ensym(select_col) )
    }

summarise_filtered_dplyrish( mtcars, am == 1, min, cyl )        # Works
summarise_filtered_dplyrish( mtcars, "am == 1", "min", "cyl" )  # Also works
```

**Brief explanation**: `{{x}}` is shorthand for `!!enquo(x)` which captures the expression provided to the function argument and the context where that expression should be evaluated. Since, your context is effectively defined by `df`, it's OK to relax `enquo` down to `enexpr` (which captures expressions but not the evaluation context) and `ensym` (which captures symbols or strings containing names of symbols).